# Hibernate Search StringBridge ClassCastException

Tags: java, hibernate, search, hibernate-search

when I try to use a StringBridge in my project I see that the objectToString(Object obj) method is being called at least twice. One time with the Object which will be mapped to a String, and a second time with the resulting String, which leads to a ClassCastException.

```
public class SchluessellisteBridge implements StringBridge {

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return "";
        }
        Schluesselliste schluesselliste = (Schluesselliste) obj;
        return schluesselliste.getLangname();
    }

}


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "rv_entscheidungArt_id")
@Field
@FieldBridge(impl = SchluessellisteBridge.class)
protected Rechtsvorgang entscheidungArt;
```

Even when I use the @DateBridge I get this behavior

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
@DateBridge(resolution = Resolution.DAY)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
```

Did I misunderstand the purpose of StringBridge????

I am using Hibernate Search 5.3 with Hibernate 4.3

```
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"
            value="filesystem" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/var/lucene/indexes" />
```

My entities are JPA Entities. For searching I use the Hibernate API like

```
List<Gesamtentscheidung> gesamtentscheidungen = null;
EntityManager em = PersistenceService.getInstance().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);

FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);


fullTextSession.beginTransaction();


QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Gesamtentscheidung.class).get();


org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder
        .keyword()
        .onFields("betreff", "tatbestaende.aktenzeichen", "entscheidungArt")
        .matching(searchString)
        .createQuery();
org.hibernate.Query hibernateQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Gesamtentscheidung.class);


gesamtentscheidungen = hibernateQuery.list();

fullTextSession.getTransaction().commit();

em.close();
return gesamtentscheidungen;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Schluesselliste schluesselliste = (Schluesselliste) obj;
```

In the above line there is issue, as this method will be called for both ObjectToString as well as StringToObject, so better you handle the object through `instanceof` before casting. or you can explore `twowayfieldbridge`